# Hamburger Moment Problem with Fractional Moments

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

It is stated in Lasserre (2010) that a sequence of real numbers $\{y_i\}$ is a valid sequence of integer moments for a positive, finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ if and only if the moment matrix defined by 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf H_n(\mathbf y)= \left [
\begin{array}{cccc}
y_0  &  y_1  &   ...  &  y_n   \\
y_1  &  y_2  &   ...  &  y_{n+1}   \\
\vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots   \\
y_n   &   y_{n+1} &  ...  &  y_{2n}
\end{array}
\right ]
\end{equation}
is positive semidefinite for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

I am wondering: is there a similar necessary and sufficient condition for a sequence of fractional (posynomial) moments $\{ y_{i/3} \}$, where
\begin{equation}
y_{i/3}=\int_\mathbb R x^{i/3}d\mu?
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moments $y_{i/3}$ for random variable $X$ are the integer moments for $X^{1/3}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Robert.  I agree with your statement.  However, I don't see how this gets me anywhere.  (Forgive me, I am not a mathematician by training.)  Can you say a little more?

Comment: Here is my best shot: Let $z_i = y_{i/3}$ for all $i \in \mathbb N \cup \{0\}$.  If $\mathbf H_n(\mathbf z) \succeq \mathbf 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, then $\{z_i\}$ is a valid sequence of integer moments for some finite positive Borel measure $\mu_Y$, where $Y=X^{1/3}$.  I suspect there is then some relationship between the measure $\mu_Y$ and the measure $\mu_X$, corresponding to the random variable $X$, which guarantees that $\mu_X$ is both finite and positive.

Comment: We may assume we're dealing with probability measures (i.e. $y_0 = 1$).  The distribution $\mu_Y$ for $Y = X^{1/3}$ is related to $\mu_X$ for $X$ by $\mu_Y(A) = \mathbb P(Y \in A) = \mathbb P(X \in A^3) = \mu_X(A^3)$ where $A^3 = \{a^3: a \in A\}$.